# Need to get specific data from array

Tags: php, functions, array

I'm building a custom carousel for a client. I've got a function which gets blocks of three images from all of the images attached to a post:

```
global $rental;

$images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $rental_id,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
) );

$array = $images;
$number_of_elements = 3;
$count = count( $array );
$split = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i <= $count - 1; $i++ ) {
    $slices = array_slice( $array, $i , $number_of_elements);
    if ( count( $slices ) != $number_of_elements )
        break;

    $split[] = $slices;
}

if ($split) :
    foreach ($split as $outeritem) :    
        echo '<div class="Outer Top">';
            foreach ($split as $inneritem) :
                echo '<div class="Inner Top">';
                echo '<img src="' . $inneritem . '">';
                echo '</div>';
             endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
endif;

//print_r( $split );
```

All I need to finalize this is to replace `inneritem` with the URL of the image. The data is all there in an array, and as you can see I just need to pull the value of *guid* for each item. The array below comes from uncommenting the `print_r( $split );` and I've removed all the extraneous data for the sake of tidiness:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 120
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15923-11-1-1.jpg
        )
        [1] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 121
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15923-12-1-1.jpg
        )
        [2] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 122
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15898.jpg
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 121
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15923-12-1-1.jpg
        )
        [1] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 122
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15898.jpg
        )
        [2] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 123
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15923-13-1-1.jpg
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 122
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15898.jpg
        )
        [1] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 123
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15923-13-1-1.jpg
        )
        [2] => WP_Post Object (
            [ID] => 124
            [guid] => http://******/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/T15923-14-1.jpg
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: What is this array output you've given us? Is it of `$split` variable?

Comment: The array you posted above, is that the `inneritem` or `outeritem`?

Comment: Why not use get_permalink()

Comment: The array above is the inneritem.

Comment: @Benoti get_permalink() gets the permalink of the parent post so doesn't help.

Comment: get_permalink($inneritem['ID']) pr $inneritem[0]['guid']

Comment: @Benoti Maybe post that as an expanded upon answer :) ?

Comment: I actually added the `$split` array because I assumed you needed all the slices back in an array. I 've posted an answer based on @Benoti suggestion to use `get_permalink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to rewrite what you have about and also use [**`get_permalink`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) as [@Benoti](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/58141/benoti) stated while omitting the `$split` array.

> [**`get_permalink`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) accepts either the Post ID or a post object.

```
global $rental;

$images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $rental_id,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
) );

$array = $images;
$number_of_elements = 3;
$count = count( $array );

for ( $i = 0; $i <= $count - 1; $i++ ) {
    $slices = array_slice( $array, $i , $number_of_elements);
    if ( count( $slices ) != $number_of_elements )
        break;

    echo "<div class='Outer Top'>";
    foreach( $slices as $inneritem ) {
        $link = wp_get_attachment_url( $inneritem->ID );
        echo "<div class='Inner Top'>";
        echo "<img src=' $link  '>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: That's getting closer, but it links to the attachment page rather than the media file.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You really don't need to have the multiple foreach's

Comment: Just needed to swap `wp_get_attachment_image_url` for `wp_get_attachment_url`. Also, it creates an extra empty instance of `<div class='Outer Top'></div>` at the end. Any ideas on how to get rid of that?

Comment: Most likely because I'm adding the outer div before checking the break clause. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test anything and read your code, but it seems that you can get_permalink() as I was told in the comment but it's true that you will get the attachment page not its url.

You can access to the object ID, guid easily

```
wp_get_attachment_url($inneritem[$i]->ID);
```

So

```
if ($split) :
foreach ($split as $outeritem) :    
    echo '<div class="Outer Top">';
    $i=0;
        foreach ($split as $inneritem) :
            echo '<div class="Inner Top">';
            echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url($inneritem[$i]->ID) . '">';
            echo '</div>';
            $i++;
         endforeach;
    echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Maybe use something like [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

Comment: That exactly what I change in my answer @Howdy.